# Bind parent's generic object field with child in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to bind parent's generic object's field with child and let that child update it.

The `ParentComponent` should render the `ChildComponent` with `item`'s `email` field as its value. And then child component should be able to update this value on the parent side.

The `item` and the `ChildComponent` can be used for any kind of object, so they will be loaded dynamically.

Here is the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-moon-8vu6b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**Parent Component**

```
interface State<Type> {
    item: Type;
}

export default class ParentComponent<Type> extends React.Component<
{},
State<Type>
> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { item: undefined };
    }

    handleInputChange = (event: any) => {
        console.log(event.currentTarget.name);
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value);

        this.setState({ !!UPDATE ITEM'S EMAIL!! }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.item);
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildComponent
                name="email"
                _handleChange={this.handleInputChange}
                value={ !!BIND ITEM'S EMAIL!! }
            />
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
interface Props {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    _handleChange: any;
}

const ChildComponent = ({ name, value, _handleChange }: Props): JSX.Element => (
    <input
        type="text"
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={_handleChange}
    />
);

export default ChildComponent;
```

**A test generic type**

```
export default class TestType {
    email: string = ' blabla@.com';
}
```

**App**

```
function App() {
    return <ParentComponent<TestType> />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Try adding this line in ParentComponent's constructor

`this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);`

Below changes are made as per your CodeSandBox

you have to set your state like this

```
 this.setState({ item: event.currentTarget.value }, () => {
  console.log("this.state.item", this.state.item);
});
```

and then in you childComponent's value you have to pass `this.state.item` instead of `!!BIND ITEM'S EMAIL!!`

Comment: I don't think that I need to put that in the constructor. The `handleInputChange` method gets called. The problem is what should I put instead of `!!UPDATE ITEM'S EMAIL!!` to update the `email` field. Please check the link aboce for the code.

Comment: The handleInputChange function will get called, but this.setState will not work unless you bind your function

Comment: Ok, I put it. Could you please tell me what should I put for the `!!UPDATE ITEM'S EMAIL!!` part please?

Comment: The project is incomplete, there are no codings in childComponent, can you do those codings, so that it'll be easy for me to help you

Comment: I've corrected the coddings. It should be ok now. thank you.

Comment: The question is binding+updating the `item` field `email`. Not himself. Think the ParentComponent as a dynamic form. And even if you bind the all `item` object with the input, you get the error `Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`. Thank you anyway.